# Pure JS scrolldown navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to learn JavaScript but finding simple samples in pure JS isn't an easy job. I wrote the following code in jQuery, but would love to create a dropdown navbar in pure JS. Any ideas on how to approach the code?

This is what I made in HTML and jQuery:

```
<nav>
        <ul>
            <a href='#' id='logo'><h2>QuokkaCentral</h2></a>
            <a href='#' id='hamburger'><li>MENU &#9776;</li></a>
            <a href='#' id='cross'><li>CLOSE X</li></a>
            <div id='navbar'>
                <a href='#' class='menu'><li>Quokka</li></a>
                <a href='#' class='menu'><li>Rottnest</li></a>
                <a href='#' class='menu'><li>Find us</li></a>
                <a href='#' class='menu'><li>Social</li></a>
            </div>
        </ul>         
</nav>


$("#navbar").hide();
$("#cross").hide();
$("#hamburger").click(function(){
    $("#navbar").slideDown(300); 
    $("#hamburger").hide();
    $("#cross").show();
});

$("#cross").click(function(){
    $("#navbar").slideUp(300);
    $("#cross").hide();
    $("#hamburger").show();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what I end up with. Hope it helps.

```js
var navbar = document.getElementById('navbar');
var cross = document.getElementById('cross');
var hamburger = document.getElementById('hamburger');

cross.style.display = "none";
navbar.style.display = "none";
hamburger.addEventListener('click', function() {
  navbar.className -= " slideUp";
  navbar.className += " slideDown";
  navbar.style.display = "block";
  hamburger.style.display = "none";
  cross.style.display = "block";
});

cross.addEventListener('click', function() {
  navbar.className -= " slideDown";
  navbar.className += " slideUp";
  setTimeout(function() {
    navbar.style.display = "none";
  }, 300);
  cross.style.display = "none";
  hamburger.style.display = "block";
});
```

```css
#navbar.slideDown {
  animation-name: slideDown;
  animation-duration: .3s;
}

#navbar.slideUp {
  animation-name: slideUp;
  animation-duration: .3s;
}

@keyframes slideDown {
  0% {
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 72.2113px;
  }
}

@keyframes slideUp {
  0% {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 72.2113px;
  }
  100% {
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <a href='#' id='logo'>
      <h2>QuokkaCentral</h2>
    </a>
    <a href='#' id='hamburger'>
      <li>MENU &#9776;</li>
    </a>
    <a href='#' id='cross'>
      <li>CLOSE X</li>
    </a>
    <div id='navbar'>
      <a href='#' class='menu'>
        <li>Quokka</li>
      </a>
      <a href='#' class='menu'>
        <li>Rottnest</li>
      </a>
      <a href='#' class='menu'>
        <li>Find us</li>
      </a>
      <a href='#' class='menu'>
        <li>Social</li>
      </a>
    </div>
  </ul>
</nav>
```